# Routing can't find ID when parameter use different ID name

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I have a URL path like this:

```
http://website.com/myController/myAction/123456
```

however, I sometimes also have this request:

```
http://website.com/myController/myAction/?myID=123456
```

This is causing problem because ASP.NET is looking ID but my parameter is called myID instead.  I can't change the name.  Is there anyway I can solve this problem?

I was trying to re-route if ID is null:

```
Server.Transfer("/myController/myAction/123456");
```

but this wasn't work, I get the Error:

```
{"Error executing child request for /myController/myAction/123456."}
```

Comment: HttpModule or just a handler in global.asax could be handy here

Comment: Can you provide an example of how that would be setup in global.asax?  Because I would need to convert the parameter myID to ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An id conversion filter can convert myID to id, so request `http://website.com/myController/myAction?myID=123456` will be converted to `http://website.com/myController/myAction/123456` through this ActionFilter.

```
public class IdConversionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["myID"] != null)
        {
            filterContext.ActionParameters.Clear();
            filterContext.ActionParameters.Add("id", Convert.ToInt32(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["myID"]));
        }
    }
}
```

Decorate myAction with IdConversionFilter

```
[IdConversionFilter]
public ActionResult myAction(int id)
{
     return View();
}
```